# Automaitcally set files to read only when put in a specific folder

Tags: windows, directory, shared-directory

I have a shared drive where we want to have a folder to put files that cannot be changed.

Currently we set the file as ready only each time we add one to the folder but I was wondering if there was a way to set the folder to assign each file to read only as you add them. We can't just set the folder itself as read only as we are constantly adding files to it.

I can't seem to find any threads with this question so was hoping one of you fine peeps could help point me in the right direction of a soluton.

Thank you!

Edit: OS - Windows 7

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else has this issue I found one solution, you can change permissions for each user to deny writing and deleting files but leaving the ability to create files

Right click folder > Security Tab > Advanced > Change Permissions > then choose to edit on the user > check deny for both delete and write options > click ok then apply